# Maintaining Consistent Data in One to Many Relationship

Tags: mysql

I have many examples of this through my database. Below is a simple example you may be able to lend assistance with.

I have an Image table

image_src
street_number
steet_name
postcode
county
country
camera_used
title
description
date_time_taken
user_id

My question is to prevent duplicate data from being added such as camera which could be the same camera for multiple image I thought it best to separate the table.

However if a user then updates the camera in the camera_used table the id in each record would correspond to the updated camera across all images. Same situation with the address.

If this instance is it best to perform a check before the update to see if any other tables reference the id and if so create an insert if not update the record.

The situation is one user updates the camera, another uses think thats not my camera updates the record and back and to we go. Just was unsure if this the best way with one to many.

Image table at present[image]

Comment: To prevent duplicate data on `camera_used`, you would add a `UNIQUE` key to it. You would then use a foreign key constraint (`camera_used`) to update the camera across all images.

Comment: I would not want to update the camera across all images however. Say John smith takes a picture with a nikon, then tony smith takes a picture with a nikon. Then tony smith updates the camera used to a canon. The camera table would update and so would the camera referenced to john smith who then thinks i did not use a canon but a nikon and changes it back

Comment: would you be able to post more schema? You could also use a composite key based on who took the picture.

Comment: You are trying to represent an NtoN relationship using a single 1-to-N relationship. You need another table to represent the fact that a photographer can use multiple cameras. So you need something like: Image (contains camera_used) -> camera_per_shot (contains both FKs) <- Photographer

Comment: i have added- makes sense for me to only store the camera once right?, image_camera table would reference image and camera table.

Comment: it is the camera and image where the issue lies- i.e. if joe smith updates the camera used for one photo say he ultimately update the camera table- the ide from this camera table may reference other images from other photographers or the same photographer- i was unsure if i perform a check before an insert or change the data layout

Comment: in other words say image one has used camera one and image two has used camera one and then image one updates camera to a different name, then image two references the updated camera name- when it should reference the original camera it was taken with

Comment: do i create a one to one and store the same camera many times or perform a check before update else do insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't allow users to update the `camera` table, at least not directly.

What they can do is update the camera used for their specific image which either finds the correct entry in `camera` or creates a new one.  You don't want to allow them to change the `camera` table directly at all or else it will change that `camera` for *all* images, as you indicated.

Comment: great exactly answer i was looking for

Comment: anyone have a link to an example?